# MongoDB saving comments to nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to both C# and MongoDB and am having some issues inserting/updating/savings items into a nested array using a repository pattern online ( http://www.primaryobjects.com/cms/article137.aspx ). Here is some code:

Models:

```
public class BlogModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public IList<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class CommentModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

And the repository pattern:

```
public void Add<T>(T item) where T : class, new()
{
    _db.GetCollection<T>().Save(item);
}

public void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class, new()
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        Add(item);
    }
}
```

How would I add a comment to the nested array using the 'Add' class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this repository pattern, there would be four steps:

1. Instantiate a repository of type *BlogModel*
2. Retrieve the document to which you want to add comments
3. Add comment(s) to the document
4. Save the document back to the collection.

Something like this:

```
var myRepository = new Repository<BlogModel>();
var myDocument = myRepository.Find(some_id);    // retrieve BlogModel document to update
myDocument.Comments.Add(some_new_comments);    // add to IList
myRepository.Add(myDocument);     // save changes to the document back to the repository
```

Note that since your *Add* repository method uses the C# Driver *Save* method, it really has the function of [insert or update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Save%3CTDocument%3Emethod).  And in this case you wouldn't have a repository of *CommentModel*, since that functions as a document array embedded in the *BlogModel* document.

Comment: Thanks dbaseman.

Do you think it would be better to add an Update class to my Repository? Allowing me to do something like...

`public void AddComment(ObjectId postId, Comment comment)
{
    _posts.Collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", Id),
        Update.PushWrapped("Comments", comment));
}`

Comment: @user1392537 Yes, I suppose that makes sense.  I'm not sure how you do that without "breaking" the generic repository pattern, though.  I guess just sub-class Repository<BlogModel> or use extension methods?